# Qt Converting time and date string into QDateTime with Timezone

Tags: c++, qt, date, datetime

I'm trying to convert a date string in the format:

```
Thu Sep 18 02:03:02 +0000 2008
```

to a QDateTime, using

```
QDateTime::FromString()
```

If I remove the +0000 timezone and use the input format:

```
ddd MMM dd hh:mm:ss yyyy
```

It works, however, it seems there is no timezone support and I can't figure out a way to ignore the timezone part using wildcards.

Is there a way to either use the timezone or just ignore the +0000 part?

Comment: Is there any chance to receive the dates in another format? `QDateTime::fromString("Thu, 18 Sep 2008 02:03:02 +0000", Qt::RFC2822Date)` for example works. The format strings don't seem to have anything about timezones indeed :/

Answer (score 1):

This is a little extreme, but you could use another date/time lib ([this one for example](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date)) just for the purpose of reformatting the string to what QDateTime wants.

```
#include "tz.h"
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace date;
    std::string input = "Thu Sep 18 02:03:02 +0000 2008";
    std::istringstream stream{input};
    sys_seconds tp;
    parse(stream, "%a %b %d %T %z %Y", tp);
    std::string output = format("%a %b %d %T %Y", tp);
    std::cout << output << '\n';
}
```

which outputs:

```
Thu Sep 18 02:03:02 2008
```

With this library the time point will be correctly converted to UTC (using the UTC offset) during the conversion.